# Two characters seem identical but UTF-8 encodings are not identical

Tags: encoding

I need to filter some illegal strings like "Password", but I found someone bypassed my check program. They input a string that seems exactly "Password" but it's not equal.
I checked the Unicode of it and, for example, the "a" is `8e61`, while normal "a" is `61` (hex).
My PHP files' encoding, HTML meta Content-Type and MySQL encoding are utf-8.

How does this happen? Why there're visually identical characters with different codes?
I want to know how can I filter these characters. 
I put the weird string here, please copy it for research:
Password

---

For some reason when I copied the "Password" with problem here, it actually displayed ASCII one.

I use PHP function bin2hex() on "Password", and get below:

```
50c28e61c28e73c28e73c28e776fc28e72c28e64c28e
```

while a normal one is:

```
50617373776f7264.
```

To make it simpler, the hexadecimal representation for "a" is:

```
c28e61
```

while normal one is:

```
61
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Welcome to the wonderful world of Unicode, too.  There are a lot of characters with multiple representations.  For a semi-exotic example, the Arabic digit one is encoded twice, once for western Arabic U+0660 and once for eastern Arabic U+06F0, but the symbol is the same; it is some of the other digits that differ.  See [In Unicode, why are there two representations for the Arabic digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676460/).  You'll have to decide whether you're going to treat U+8E61 the same as U+0061 _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ Hold on; U+8E61 is a Unified Han symbol.  Which code page are you using?  0x8E61 is not valid UTF-8; the 0x8E is a continuation byte, and the 0x61 is LATIN SMALL LETTER A, which can't be followed by a continuation byte.  You've not given all the information we need; what is the entire byte sequence you're dealing with?  The comments above are still accurate and more or less relevant, but you are unlikely to be treating U+8E61 as if it was U+0061.

Comment: I copied your string and it is identified as containing: `0x0000: 50 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64  Password`.  That's the regular ASCII representation of Password.  So either your copy/paste didn't preserve the odd characters, or mine didn't.  I'm working on a Mac.  Can you identify the bytes you think you have in hex?

Comment: (Oops: U+0660 and U+06F0 are Arabic zeroes, not ones; U+0661 and U+06F1 are the ones.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, hex string provided, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the hex string `50c28e61c28e73c28e73c28e776fc28e72c28e64c28e`, you have an encoding of a valid UTF-8 string:

```
0x50      = U+0050 = P
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x61      = U+0061 = a
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x73      = U+0073 = s
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x73      = U+0073 = s
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x77      = U+0077 = w
0x6F      = U+006F = o
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x72      = U+0072 = r
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
0x64      = U+0064 = d
0xC2 0x8E = U+008E = SS2
```

The 0xC2 0x8E sequence maps to ISO 8859-1 0x8E, which is a control character SS2 or Single Shift 2 (see [Unicode Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)).  SS2 doesn't have a defined visible representation.  The string is clearly different from plain 'Password'.  As long as you don't strip out control characters, you should be able to spot the difference as a string comparison should not treat that as identical to plain 'Password'.

Comment: Thank you ! How to remove this character in PHP, or this kind of characters? I searched some, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string, but they can't remove this character.

Comment: I've found the solution to remove it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295125/preg-replace-to-strip-out-non-printing-characters-seems-to-remove-all-foreign-ch

Answer (score 0):

What you might be seeing (I can't tell exactly because parts of your question don't make sense or are inconsistent) are so-called *homoglyphs*. Those are characters that look identical or very similar and thus can be mistaken at first glance. To circumvent your check people can use a Cyrillic *a* and get away with it. But frankly, this isn't actually a problem because I know no password cracker that will actually try mixing scripts, as most passwords are ASCII-only.

As for the *why*, you can take a look at [Why are there duplicate characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1741236/73070).